# Relationship between two or more webform

Tags: 7, webforms

Example:

Webform A: Fill up Particular
Webform B: Choose your product

Webform A Result: Peter, male, 22
Webform B Result: I want product A and B

Webform A Result: Mary, female, 21
Webform B Result: I want product A and C

When I view Peter particular, how to display webform B which state he wants product A and B. May I know how to do that?